# Angular . Problem to create new component

Tags: angular, module, frontend, components, createjs

Angular . Problem to create new component.

More than one module matches. Use the skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module or use the module option to specify a module.

More than one module matches. Use the skip-import option to skip importing the component into the closest module or use the module option to specify a module

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.